# NSXMLParser not showing error log

Tags: ios

How can i catch error of NSXMLParser in console ?

My project are using offical "LazyTableImages".

problem is its not working all the time and the table not getting any value .

here is what ive done to get some debug info :

placing "cachePolicy:0 and timeoutInterval:160.0" to avoid url timeout :

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TopPaidAppsFeed] cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:160.0]
```

then adding "NSLog(@"data: %@", string)" to check if i have xml currect:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:self.dataToParse];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.dataToParse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data: %@", string);
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

the console shows the xml with these at start and any thing else was ok on it :

```
2014-02-24 11:54:30.566 MyXMlParserTest[1419:1403] data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

after that i put this on parseError to check for error but nothing happend:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{

    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download data (Error code %i )",[parseError code]];

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString
                                                         delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlert show];
}
```

then i put "NSLog(@"nodeCount)" on connectionDidFinishLoading :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.appListFeedConnection = nil;   // release our connection

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;   

    // create the queue to run our ParseOperation
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // create an ParseOperation (NSOperation subclass) to parse the RSS feed data
    // so that the UI is not blocked
    ParseOperation *parser = [[ParseOperation alloc] initWithData:self.appListData];

    parser.errorHandler = ^(NSError *parseError) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self handleError:parseError];
        });
    };

    // Referencing parser from within its completionBlock would create a retain
    // cycle.
    __weak ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;

    parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {
        if (weakParser.appRecordList) {
            // The completion block may execute on any thread.  Because operations
            // involving the UI are about to be performed, make sure they execute
            // on the main thread.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // The root rootViewController is the only child of the navigation
                // controller, which is the window's rootViewController.
                RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];

                rootViewController.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
                NSUInteger nodeCount = [rootViewController.entries count];
                NSLog(@"nodeCount: %lu", (unsigned long)nodeCount);
                // tell our table view to reload its data, now that parsing has completed
                [rootViewController.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }

        // we are finished with the queue and our ParseOperation
        self.queue = nil;
    };

    [self.queue addOperation:parser]; // this will start the "ParseOperation"

    // ownership of appListData has been transferred to the parse operation
    // and should no longer be referenced in this thread
    self.appListData = nil;
}
```

and it returns :

```
014-02-24 11:54:30.582 MyXMlParserTest[1419:a0b] nodeCount: 0
```

from this point i dont where to check.
i tried this both on real and simulator device and same result happend.
1 of 10 time it works and table filled. 9 other time nothing happend.
the string tag of xml is same all time. only image url tag are changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after chaging this line :

```
__weak ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;
```

to either of these :

```
 ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;
```

or

```
__block ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;
```

problem goes away.